# If condition are met play video not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have the below code that does not seem to be working correctly. The video should only play if there are no empty Divs and if none of those Divs have the class "wrong" however currently the video plays whenever the button is clicked. It's completely ignoring the conditions and always playing when the run button is clicked.

so the code states that when the "run" button is clicked if the Divs starting with "Drop" are not empty and do not have the class "wrong" play the map1 video.

I've tried and i can't seem to figure out why its completely ignoring the conditions.

js:

```
$("#run").click(function(){       
    if ($("[id^='Drop']").not(":empty") && $("[id^='Drop']").not(".wrong")){
     $('#map1').get(0).play();
    };
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or any runny html dom

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting inside your If block?  Does #run have a default event that you need to prevent (with event.preventDefault())?

Comment: the run button also carries out 2 other functions? could this be causing the problem.

Comment: @TryingAtCode, yes, that could be problematic depending on what the other 2 functions do.  Why not try removing the other 2 functions to see if the video starts playing correctly?  If it does, then consider binding just a single click event that does everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple IDs is not valied, use classes instead

You can chain selections and filter out `:empty`  and `.wrong` as whole and check for length of return elements if it is  zero

```
 $("#run").click(function(){       
   if ($("[id^='Drop']").filter(":empty").filter(".wrong").length==0){
    alert("yes")
    };
  });
```

**Demo:**

```js
 $("#run").click(function(){       
   if ($("[id^='Drop']").filter(":empty").filter(".wrong").length==0){
    alert("yes")
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Drop">
 <p>asas</p> 
</div>
<div id="Drop">
 <p>asas</p> 
</div>
<button id="run"> run </button>
```